# Validate data using express-validator in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-validator

I have created a validate that for validate every data before create, but i am not sure that my validator works. So, i would like to ask for help about this and i hope community can help me to improve my validator. I would like to receive your feedback and suggestions, if there's something wrong please tell me

```
// car.validator.js 
import { body } from "express-validator";

export var validateCar = () => {
  var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/;
  var valid = regex.test(req.body.name);
  if (!req.body.name && !valid) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Name can not be empty or not contains special characters",
    });
    return;
  } else if (!req.body.color) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Color can not be empty!",
    });
    return;
  } else if (!req.body.brand) {
    res.status(400).send({
      message: "Brand can not be empty!",
    });
    return;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to use `express-validator` with node js is:

Suppose I assume you are using `/cars/create` endpoint to send POST request which creates entry of car in your db then in your route file should be:

```
const { check } = require("express-validator");
router.post(
  "/cars/create",
  [
    check('name')
        .escape()
        .notEmpty()
        .matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/),
    check("color").notEmpty(),
    check("brand").notEmpty(),
  ],
  carsController.createCar
);
```

In your carsController.createCar you will have array of errors if validation is failed:

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const createCar = async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()){
      return res
        .status(200)
        .json({ err: "Invalid Data Passed!", errors: errors });
    }

    // code to be implemented if validation is passed
}
```

check [this](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) doc for more details and your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
//car.validator.js
import { check } from "express-validator";

export var validateCar = () => {
  var validate = [
    check("name")
      .escape()
      .notEmpty()
      .matches(/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/),
    check("color").notEmpty(),
    check("brand").notEmpty(),
  ];
  return validate;
};
```

Car Controller:

```
import { validationResult } from "express-validator";
// create new car
export async function createCar(req, res) {
  const car = new Car({
    car_id: id,
    name: req.body.name,
    color: req.body.color,
    brand: req.body.brand,
  });
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({ err: "Invalid Data Passed!", errors: errors });
  }
  try {
    let newCar = await car.save();
    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: "New course created successfully",
      Car: newCar,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Server error. Please try again.",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
}
```